# ERR_SSL_UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE error in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl

I`m experiencing a challenge coding a TLS function in node.js and can`t find a root cause.

This is the scenario:

1. Client sends a https CONNECT request to the app
2. The APP is working as a http/https proxy
3. The APP replies the client back with a 200OK
4. Next request from client is TLS client hello sent through the tunnel
   established by the CONNECT request
5. The APP crashes instead of replying TLS handshake with a server
   hello

Here is the error I`m getting:

```
Emitted 'error' event on TLSSocket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  function: 'ossl_statem_client_read_transition',
  reason: 'unexpected message',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE'
}
```

And here is the code:

```
proxyServerHttp.on('connect', (request, socket, head) => {
    handleHttpConnectMethod(request, socket, head);
})

function handleHttpConnectMethod(request, socket, head) {
    socket.write('HTTP/' + request.httpVersion + ' 200 OK\r\n\r\n', 'UTF-8');
    connectTlsSocket(socket);

}

function connectTlsSocket(socket) {
    let options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
        ca: [fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')],
        socket: socket
    }
    tls.connect(options) //error is thrown when this line is executed
}
```

Any help is super welcome

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after debugging and looking at node src code, I found the issue.

```
function connectTlsSocket(socket)
```

return a tls.socket object in client mode (default), so the socket was working in client mode and receiving 'Hello Client' from the source.

I had to create a socket obj in server mode in order to fix the issue.

```
function connectTlsSocket(socket) {
    //let tlsSocketParameters = getCertAndKey();
    //tlsSocketParameters.socket = socket;
    let options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
        ca: [fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')],
        isServer: true,
        requestCert: false
    }

    let tlsSocket = new tls.TLSSocket(socket, options);
    tlsSocket.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    
}
```